# How do I convince MS office I'm running a "newer version of windows"?

Tags: playonlinux, microsoft-office

Okay, so I recently installed linux and I'm trying to install Microsoft Office 2016 (Home and student edition). I try the solution witn Play on Linux. First I ran into some problems (PoL couldn't finish the download) but I fixed that by putting the .exe-file into the PoL "Ressources"-folder.

That seemed to allow PoL to download the file and to install MS Office, however I then ran into a new problem. MS Office generated the following message:

[image]

.....And after that PoL generated its own error message, claiming that something might be wrong with the program.

How do I fix this? Can I somehow make PoL convince the office file that Iäm actually running Windows 10 or higher?

I'm aware that there are other threads discussing the installation on office on linux, but I didn't see any of them adressing this particular error message.

Comment: What happens if press stand ( as in 'I stand by my decision not to install Windows 10' )?

Comment: It's not stand but "stäng" (close in swedish)

Comment: Thanks Magnus. I didn't know that. And now that I picked up my new glasses this morning I can see it clearly. Sorry about that, forget the comment.